# NSString stringWithFormat question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am trying to build a small table using NSString. I cannot seem to format the strings properly.

Here is what I have

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%8@: %.6f",e,v]
```

where e is an NSString from somewhere else, and v is a float.

What I want is output something like this:

```
Grapes:       20.3
Pomegranates:  2.5
Oranges:      15.1
```

What I get is

```
Grapes:20.3
Pomegranates:2.5
Oranges:15.1
```

How can I fix my format to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDictionary* fruits = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.3], @"Grapes",
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.5], @"Pomegranates",
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.1], @"Oranges",
                        nil];
NSUInteger longestNameLength = 0;
for (NSString* key in [fruits allKeys])
{
    NSUInteger keyLength = [key length];
    if (keyLength > longestNameLength)
    {
        longestNameLength = keyLength;
    }
}
for (NSString* key in [fruits allKeys])
{
    NSUInteger keyLength = [key length];
    NSNumber* object = [fruits objectForKey:key];
    NSUInteger padding = longestNameLength - keyLength + 1;
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%*s%5.2f", key, padding, " ", [object floatValue]]);
}
```

Output:

```
Oranges:      15.10
Pomegranates:  2.50
Grapes:       20.30
```

Answer (score 6):

you could try using - stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:

Answer (score 1):

The NSNumberFormatter class is the way to go!

Example:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numFormatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
[numFormatter setFormatWidth:2];
NSString *paddedString = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:integer]];
[numFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-9@ %6.1f",[e stringByAppendingString:@":"],v]
```

since you want padding in front of the float to make it fit the column, though if the NSString is longer than 8, it will break the columns.

`%-8f` left-aligns the string in a 9-character-wide column (9-wide since the `:` is appended to the string beforehand, which is done so the `:` is at the end of the string, not after padding spaces); `%6.1f` right-aligns the float in a 6-char field with 1 decimal place.

*edit*: also, if you're viewing the output as if it were HTML (through some sort of web view, for instance), that may be reducing any instances of more than one space to a single space.