# String Formatting Tricks/Docs

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, string

Was reading the response by Shaggy Frog to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700909/nsstring-stringwithformat-question) and was intrigued by the following line of code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%*s%5.2f", key, padding, " ", [object floatValue]]);
```

I know string formatting is an age old art but I'm kinda doing the end around into Cocoa/Obj-C programming and skipped a few grades along the way. Where is a good (best) place to learn all the string formatting tricks allowed in NSString's `stringWithFormat`?  I'm familiar with Apple's [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) page but from what I can tell it doesn't shed light on whatever is happening with `%*s` or the `%5.2f` (not to mention the 3 apparent placeholders followed by 4 arguments) above?!?

Comment: I can see why `NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"...", ...]);` was used in that answer (to parallel the question), but `NSLog(@"...", ...);` should work identically and it reads more easily.

Comment: `%*s` is a printf feature from C99

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of *-stringWithFormat* leads you to [String Format Specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) which in turn sends you to the [IEEE printf specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html). That's about as much information as you'll ever want.

The only notable exception:

> ### %@
>
> Objective-C object, printed as the
>   string returned by
>   *descriptionWithLocale:* if available,
>   or *description* otherwise. Also works
>   with *CFTypeRef* objects, returning the
>   result of the *CFCopyDescription*
>   function.

- *nil* gets converted to *(null)*, that's the reason why `NSLog(@"%@", someObject)` is safer than `NSLog("someObject)`. The later might crash when *someObject* is *nil*:

You might also be interested in the [wikipedia page about string formatting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#printf_format_placeholders).

Comment: ya. that i know.. what i don't know is a good source describing all the printf string argument manipulation tricks/techniques.

Comment: `man printf` is a good place to start (the Cocoa methods follow the same practices, which the additions listed above), although the wiki page linked above is basically just a fancy form of the `printf` man page. For example, `%*s` uses two specifies, `*` and `s`; both are described on the man page (`*` in the "width" section, and `s` in the type section).