# Objective-C string formatting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Format string, integer with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985170/format-string-integer-with-leading-zeros)
>   [String Formatting Tricks/Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701538/string-formatting-tricks-docs)

I have a really simple question but didn´t find document about.

I am using this code :

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i.mp3", i];
```

so the @"0%i.mp3" = 01.mp3, 02.mp3 ... 09.mp3 files

My issue is I have this mp3 with a longer name like 01-thefirstsong.mp3 , 02-mysecondsong.mp3 ... 15-mylastsong.mp3

How can I write this like @"allmyfiles.mp3"   ?

Regards

Comment: I am also looking for documentation about that. Thanks

Comment: See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985170/format-string-integer-with-leading-zeros

Answer (score 27):

If you use this

```
int i = 1;
NSString *name = @"thefirstsong";
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0d-%@.mp3", i, name];
```

`filename` will contain `01-thefirstsong.mp3`.

`%@` is the placeholder for objectiveC strings (NSString).

Comment: %s is actually, %@ stands for object