# What does stringWithFormat "%.16f" mean?

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c

I'm porting some Objective C (a language I have never used...) over to a C# project and have come into the following line:

```
altStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<altitude>%.16f</altitude>", alt]; //alt === double
```

In C# I'm pretty sure this translates to:

```
altStr = string.Format("<altitude>{0}</altitude>", alt); //alt === double
```

However, I can't find anywhere what `%.16f` specifically means. I know that `f` means it's a double, but what about the `.16` part? Something to do with number of decimal places?

Comment: %.16f means: print as a floating point with a precision of sixteen characters after the decimal point

Comment: [It's in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String Formatting Tricks/Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701538/string-formatting-tricks-docs)

Comment: @J... No it didn't answer my question and nothing in the docs says anything about what what `.16` might have meant, or any number for that matter.

Comment: @d4zed Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @StuartAitken They both answer your question, you just have to read them.  It's all in the linked IEEE printf documentation.

Comment: @J... okay so it was in the IEEE documentation, not the Apple developer docs you provided. Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%.16f` means printing a floating point number, with a precision of `16` digits, so more specific it will translate in C# to the following:

```
altStr = string.Format("<altitude>{0}</altitude>", Math.Round(alt, 16));
```

Comment: Thanks, that cracked it. (Though it should be noted that `Math.Round(alt, 16)` fails because the limit is 15d.p. for Math.Round. I wrote my own rounding method instead)